# How to test Angular 7 ngOnInIt that has a promise?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, jasmine, ionic5

I wanted to test a simple assignment done by my ngoninit function.

The ngOnInIt function is basically doing this:

```
async ngOnInit() {
     Promise.all([
      this.storage.get('current-data'),
      this.storage.get('uuid'),
    ]).then(async (values) => {
 
  const dataObject: any = values[0];
  const uuid = values[1];

  // get the data object for this data

  await this.dataService
    .getAllData()
    .then((data) => {
          this.data = data;
    });
 });
```

}
}

So basically,

I wanted to test the length of data but I keep getting the following error:

```
ERROR: 'Unhandled Promise rejection:', 'Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')', '; Zone:', 'ProxyZone', '; Task:', 'Promise.then', '; Value:', TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')
    at apply (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/src/app/pages/survey/survey.page.spec.ts:128:32)
    at _ZoneDelegate.invoke (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:409:30)
    at ProxyZoneSpec.onInvoke (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-testing.js:303:43)
    at _ZoneDelegate.invoke (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:408:56)
    at Zone.run (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:169:47)
    at apply (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:1326:38)
    at _ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:443:35)
    at ProxyZoneSpec.onInvokeTask (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-testing.js:334:43)
    at _ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:442:64)
    at Zone.runTask (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:214:51), 'TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')
    at apply (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/src/app/pages/survey/survey.page.spec.ts:128:32)
    at _ZoneDelegate.invoke (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:409:30)
    at ProxyZoneSpec.onInvoke (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-testing.js:303:43)
    at _ZoneDelegate.invoke (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:408:56)
    at Zone.run (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:169:47)
    at apply (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:1326:38)
    at _ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:443:35)
    at ProxyZoneSpec.onInvokeTask (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-testing.js:334:43)
    at _ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:442:64)
```

And on my spec.ts file here is the code I've written for testing it.

```
describe('initialzation', async () => {
        beforeEach(async () => {
          const dataService =
            fixture.debugElement.injector.get(DataService);
          const spy = spyOn(dataService, 'getAllData').and.returnValue(
            Promise.resolve(stubValueData)
          );
          (StorageServiceSpy.get as any)
            .withArgs({ key: 'current-data' })
            .and.returnValue(Promise.resolve(JSON.stringify(stubValueCurrentData)));
          (StorageServiceSpy.get as any)
            .withArgs({ key: 'uuid' })
            .and.returnValue(Promise.resolve(uniqueId));
          (StorageServiceSpy.get as any)
            .withArgs({ key: 'data' })
            .and.returnValue(Promise.resolve(JSON.stringify(stubValueData)));
    
          fixture.detectChanges();
        });
    
        it('should verify that the arguments are all set', async () => {
          fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
            // wait for async getData
            fixture.detectChanges(); // update view with Tasks
            expect(component.data.length).toEqual(stubValueData.length);
            
          });
        });
      });
```

The TestBed.configureTestingModule is:

```
beforeEach(async () => {
    routeStub = {
      snapshot: {
        paramMap: convertToParamMap({
          data_id: String(stubValueDatas[0].data_id),
        }),
      },
    };

    const spyStorage = jasmine.createSpyObj('Storage', [
      'create',
      'get',
      'set',
    ]);
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [SurveyPage],
      imports: [IonicModule.forRoot(), RouterTestingModule],
      providers: [
        {
          provide: Storage,
          useValue: spyStorage,
        },
        { provide: ActivatedRoute, useValue: routeStub },
        {
          provide: NavController,
          useClass: NavMock,
        },
        HttpClient,
        HttpHandler,
      ],
    }).compileComponents();

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(SurveyPage);
    StorageServiceSpy = TestBed.inject(Storage) as jasmine.SpyObj<Storage>;
    navControllerSpy = TestBed.inject(
      NavController
    ) as jasmine.SpyObj<NavController>;
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
    await fixture.whenStable();
  });
```

Can you help me fix the error? I don't understand why I get undefined length. It should work. I don't want to catch the error in the spec.ts file because the other except functions will not work when they get an error if i do that.

Comment: Can you show `TestBed.configureTestingModule`? Are you calling `fixture.detectChanges` before the first one you have presented? The first `fixture.detectChanges` is when `ngOnInit` is called.

Comment: Hi,
I have included the TestBed.configureTestingModule in the question. I am calling fixture.detectChanges first. Is that what's causing the error?

Comment: The problem is it is not even making it to the Promise in my ngOnInIt. It doesn't get there. I have tried to log a statement from inside of the promise and it doesn't show.

Answer (score 0):

Remove these lines in the first `beforeEach` (TestBed.configureTestingModule).

```
    fixture.detectChanges();
    await fixture.whenStable();
```

And add them on the 2nd `beforeEach`.

```
beforeEach(async () => {
          const dataService =
            fixture.debugElement.injector.get(DataService);
          const spy = spyOn(dataService, 'getAllData').and.returnValue(
            Promise.resolve(stubValueData)
          );
          (StorageServiceSpy.get as any)
            .withArgs({ key: 'current-data' })
            .and.returnValue(Promise.resolve(JSON.stringify(stubValueCurrentData)));
          (StorageServiceSpy.get as any)
            .withArgs({ key: 'uuid' })
            .and.returnValue(Promise.resolve(uniqueId));
          (StorageServiceSpy.get as any)
            .withArgs({ key: 'data' })
            .and.returnValue(Promise.resolve(JSON.stringify(stubValueData)));
    
          fixture.detectChanges();
          await fixture.whenStable();
        });
```

The issue is in the first `beforeEach`, we are calling `fixture.detectChanges()` and this causes `ngOnInit` to run but we did not mock the dependencies of `ngOnInit` yet and therefore it complains that those are not promises.

Also, remove the `async` here, it does nothing:

```
describe('initialzation', async () => {
```

Comment: It is still raising the same errors. The length is undefined.

Comment: Strange, sorry, I am not sure then.